# Removing Line Breaks and Newlines in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

CKEditor is adding new lines in my content that's entered into my database, which is fine, except that this data needs to be rendered to javascript as a single line of html.

In my PHP I have:

```
$tmpmaptext = $map['maptext'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')];
$tmpmaptext = html_entity_decode($tmpmaptext, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$tmpmaptext = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n', '\r', '\t'), '', $tmpmaptext);
$tmpmaptext = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $tmpmaptext);
```

Which is pretty much everything I can find on how to remove new lines but I'm still ending up with this in the page:

```
var infowindow01 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  
        content:  '<div><h2>Title</h2>

<p>Address line 1,<br />
Address line 2</p>

<p>phone number</p>

<p><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></p>
</div>'
```

How can I get all these new lines out without removing that normal spacing between characters?

Comment: Why not write a simple regex to remove sequences like line ending / white space / line ending?

Comment: Try use nl2br(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: I also tried `$tmpmaptext = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tmpmaptext);` but that goes too far by removing all the spacing.  I don't know the regex for removing new lines or I would try it.

Comment: @VinceKronlein `\n` is newline, `\r` is carriage return. Put characters in square brackets to match any characters in the set. Also you probably want to replace it with a single newline, not an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're using single-quotes in str_replace which will search for the string '\n' (slash n). If you use double-quotes it will convert \n to the newline character...

```
$maptext = '<div><h2>Title</h2>

<p>Address line 1,<br />
Address line 2</p>

<p>phone number</p>

<p><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></p>
</div>';

$no_newlines = str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n", "\r", "\t", "    "), "", $maptext);

echo($no_newlines);
```

outputs:

```
<div><h2>Title</h2><p>Address line 1,<br />Address line 2</p><p>phone number</p><p><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></p></div>
```

Comment: Also, if you replace "\t" with "    " (4 spaces) in the search array, it will get rid of the big gaps.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
$tmpmaptext = $map['maptext'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')];
$tmpmaptext = preg_replace('/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/', '', $tmpmaptext);
```

Was able to remove all the rest and it renders perfectly now.